# Does wrapping methods impact performance or will the compiler optimize the calls

Tags: java, performance, refactoring

I just had a thought and would like to know if someone can help, this does not have to be specific to one language but if I have a method in a class that is then used by another method in a class and so on(Don't ask why, I just saw it in a project). Does it have any negative impact?

eg.

Class_A has method_1
Class_B has method_2
Class_C has method_3

and then method_3 calls method_2 and method_2 calls method_1.

Comment: If it does, it isn't on the level to worry about. If you want to know exact values, you could do a benchmark to find out.

Comment: While benchmarking is an option, it's also *incredibly easy* to get misleading numbers on microbenchmarks like this. Doing them the right way, is definitely non-trivial.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

In many situations a simple delegating method can be optimized away either by the compiler or the runtime. Java, for example, does almost all of its optimizations at runtime, many other languages (especially older ones) tend to do that at compile-time.

But whether or not a specific method will be optimized away (or inlined) depends on many different factors and can't definitely be answered in the abstract.